# Unable to get driver to recognize NVIDIA GPU when I followed instructions for tensorflow install for 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, tensorflow

I am following the instructions here https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

My output for `nvidia-smi` was "No devices were found."
However when I run `lspci -vv | grep NVI` I get

```
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f06 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
0a:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f9 (rev a1)
0a:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1ada (rev a1) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
0a:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1adb (rev a1)
```

When I run the bug report, `nvidia-bug-report-sh` I get this (very) long output

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Gn60tmK1FUP_DskXlcgB0k2Y1ruL4yyO

One thing that stood out to me was the fact that it says

```
ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";
```

I am unsure of how to do that or if it will fix the problem.